# Assign Ajax Html Text Editor content to div in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign Ajax HTML text editor content to div in c#. 
But I can't able to do that.

I am doing this.

This is Data inside **txtTermsandCondions**
[image: Content]

This is the code to assign HTML Text Editor Content to Div element.

```
XDocument xDoc = GetNewsLetterXDocument();
        var divdoc = xDoc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("div") && (d.Attribute("id").Value != "uploadofferImages"));

        var docText = xDoc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.Equals("div")).ToList();
        var termsAndConditionsSpan = docText.Where(d => d.Attribute("id") != null && d.Attribute("id").Value == "termsAndConditionsText").FirstOrDefault();
        if (termsAndConditionsSpan != null)
        {
            termsAndConditionsSpan.Value = txtTermsandCondions.Content.;
        }
```

And it is rendering like this,
[image: Rendered Content]

And The Rendered HTML is this,
[image: Rendered HTML Content]

How do i Solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning your variable `txtTermsandCondions` and don't use `var` in submissions so we can see what the real type is

Comment: txtTermsandCondions is a HTML Text Editor Control Id

Comment: Is there an `InnerText` property that you can use then?

Comment: which ajax text editor you are using?

Comment: HTML Text editor from AjaxcontrolToolkit

Answer (score 1):

set the `InnerHtml` property as below

```
termsAndConditionsSpan.InnerHtml  = txtTermsandCondions.Content;
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply... I have checked for InnerHtml property. But it is not there..

Comment: use termsAndConditionsSpan.innerHTML="anything"